Are uncovered cord plugs safe to use in the snow?
I was recently given some christmas outdoor decorations that have piggyback plugs (prongs on one end, socket on the other - not sure if this is the right term). They're all two-prong so plugging them all together into an extension cord looks like this:

I'm used to these sorts of plugs for indoor lights, but not for outdoor ones. Since this is going to be outside, it will likely be buried in snow for a couple months at a time. Is it safe to leave these plugs on the ground like that?
I don't like the idea of leaving the exposed socket in the snow so I've considered wrapping it in plastic and duct taping it shut, but if moisture gets trapped in there that might just make things worse. That said, I found it difficult to find off-the-shelf solutions which makes me think this isn't an issue, but I'd like to hear a second opinion. It will be plugged into a GFCI outlet so there's that protection at least.

Plugged into a GFCI, CSA marked outdoor light string - should be fine as is, and if it's not, the GFCI will let you know you need to bother to take any additional steps.
Snow is not all that conductive, and it has presumably been tested in order to get the CSA mark. Outdoors if it's an outdoor light string.
At a low level of bother, elevating it from the ground (set it on a brick or the like) and inverting a bucket over it should keep it out of puddles and keep the snow off it with minimal fuss. Put a rock on top of the bucket if you get high wind exposure.

I agree with "Will probably be fine" but clearly this is NOT designed for outdoor use - probably the string is, but the vendor expects the plug to be protected / indoors.

"Snow is not all that conductive" - yes, but snow can melt if the temperature is close to 0 °C. The plug can warm up if there is a poor connection and/or high load.

I've been doing that for twenty or more years heavy duty extension with integral GFCI to the front porch cedar and junipers first few years with incandescent lights and then various LED types being added the incandescent ones long gone. With what the LEDs draw no problems.

I always tape the crap out of the connections, but I think you are right that it's probably OK.

@MikeB In case you're not familiar with these types of lights, the other end of the string can have a female plug to chain sets together. If the set is rated for outdoor use it would mean the whole set, not just everything past the plug.

What makes you assume the CSA mark is anything other than decoration which the manufacturer believed was traditional?

@MarkMorganLloyd Mark owners actively defend them, e.g. https://www.csagroup.org/testing-certification/marks-labels/brand-protection/reporting-suspect-counterfeit-marks

@Ecnerwal Sure they do: if they can work out who's infringing, and think they're worth pursuing.

You can get waterproof electrical connection boxes.  (Pic from Amazon.)

Link - https://a.co/d/iTZ6Yrp

Stack Exchange policies require that images which are not the creative work of the poster be properly attributed via a link to where the image was found. Please update your posting to bring this into compliance.

As you wish....

You need to provide an actual link to satisfy the Stack Exchange policy. Just saying where you saw it is not sufficient.

It is safe(ish). I've been using such cords across roofs and lawns in my snowy climate for decades. I don't recall even a blown integrated fuse, let alone any sort of shock. Even rain isn't likely a problem.
Just don't go grabbing a cord in a puddle unless you unplug it first.

Like treating firearms as always loaded, when you are deploying or servicing electrics presume in your mind that you are handling 240v 30a as the klutz character in a safety cartoon (lots of zaps).

Those GFCI cord dongles are cheap and easy to use, so even if a belt-and-suspenders deal, is a good idea.

Nail an old Tupperware aka plastic box with the open end downwards to a post.
fix the extension cord with sockets so they are up inside the protection of the box. Should be fine - rain, snow etc...
Or go to one of those hardware / garden stores and buy the waterproof plastic rock socket thing...

For years I have tucked these ends into plastic bags. (Like baggies or sandwich bags, not thin grocery bags.)  Then applied a little plumbers putty around the wires and tightly taped the end of the bag shut.
It works well in drenching rain, here in Fla. I had done the same thing when I lived in Ohio and snow was no problem either.

Theoretically no, as you can't guarantee that snow is never melting. Its not save as electricity could be transmitted in wet earth/snow (if it starts melting, when its frozen its somehow safe). The chance for the RCD tripping is quit high in moist outdoor environments. From the type of plug I guess u live in the US so I do not know if u even are required to have RCDs installed.
Practically its somehow save since RCD will protect harm to people and for short circuit water is not conductive enough. as others recommended get a box where u can hide it from the influence of the weather. If not u may expect creepage currents which can consume some power and cause corrosion.
